# user_id returned as null though the object and the id is created in mongo.db (graphql, node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I am new to programming (node.js and graphql in particular). I was following an Udemy course and the code that I re-used doesn't work the way I expected. It might be something obvious that I am missing. I double-checked everything and from my perspective, it should work, but it doesn't. Please advise.

I am creating a user using mongodb, mongoose, and graphql.

Schema:

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    description: 'Documentation for user',
    fields: () => ({
        user_id: {type: GraphQLID},
        name: {type: GraphQLString},
        last_name: {type: GraphQLString},
        age: {type: GraphQLInt},
        profession: {type: GraphQLString},

        tasks: {
            type: new GraphQLList(TaskType),
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return _.filter(tasksData, {userId: parent.user_id});
            }
        },

        events: {
            type: new GraphQLList(EventType),
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return _.filter(eventsData, {userId: parent.user_id});
            }
        },
    })
 });
```

Mongoose Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const MSchema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = MSchema({
    name: String,
    last_name: String,
    age: Number, 
    profession: String,
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Query

```
mutation {
    createUser(name: "Capu", age: 3, last_name: "Don",  profession: "cat") {
    user_id
  }
}
```

Response

```
{
  "data": {
    "createUser": {
      "user_id": null
    }
  }
}
```

MongoDB object
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going on. If I rename 'user_id' (the property I wanted to use) into just 'id', I get the id returned just as expected. Id field seems to be a thing in mongodb and I am not sure there is a way to rename it. I'll work on it later.